# Не выводятся русские символы на канвас

Tags: android, java

Не выводятся русские символы на канвас в стандартном метотде `drawText`, латинские символы выводятся нормально. На планшете русский язык выбран в качестве используемого постоянно.

**Добавлено.**

Символы вводятся с клавиатуры. Обработчик `OnKeyListener` проверяет условие

```
event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
```

Когда печатаю английскую букву, такое событие приходит, когда русскую - нет.

Comment: Пример кода желательно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего неверная кодировка символов. В Android кодировка должна быть UTF-8. Проверьте настройки своего IDE и поставьте кодировку исходников на UTF-8 и все заработает.

Comment: Я считываю символ с клавиатуры и вывожу его на канвас. Позже выложу код, тогда, думаю, подскажут точнее.